# bind click event to element and children in angular linker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a directive which is basically a big table. In some of the cells in the table, I have divs with some content. Whenever a div is clicked I would like to do something (exemplified by the `console.log("clicked")` in my code below).

The thing is that the div contains other html-elements as well, and if one of the descendant html-elements are clicked nothing happens. So I would like to do something both when the parent div is clicked and when any descendant elements are clicked.

The following does something when the div is clicked but not when any descendant is clicked:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  element.on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.className.match('myclass')) 
       {
         console.log("Clicked!");
       }
    });
   }
```

How do I make sure the above happens when clicking the div AND any element inside the element with "myclass"?

Comment: the event is firing, but your if condition is filtering so the console.log("Clicked!") is executed only for the element with the class myClass (I understand only your div has this class set). In that case, removing the if should work fine

Comment: I updated the question to better explain my issue

Comment: if you remove the `if (e.target.className.match('myclass'))` does it work ? it will log every time you click the div or its descendants

Comment: I made this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qeqd3vtL/ If you click the text "I can be clicked" then something happens. But when you click the text "I want to be clicked", then nothing happens. I want something to happen when something in the "myclass"-div or one of it's children are clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need in your event is

```
if (e.target.className.match('myclass') || $(e.target).closest('.myclass')) {
      alert("Clicked!");
    }
```

the function [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)  allows you to search in the parents.

(I assume you have jQuery in your project because is part of the tags)

Having said that, I strongly discourage you to mix jQuery and AngularJs unless is necessary. You could achieve similar functionality without using jQuery at all in your project in most cases.

I believe you could get the same functionality if in your template for each div you just use `ng-click="someFunction()"` - it will fire when clicked from children elements

Comment: I ended up using the "closest"-function. Thanks!